# Create floor plan in Android

Tags: android, canvas, view, draw

In my application i need to create a floor, which contains some **zones and cabins** inside the zones. I am getting the coordinates of the ***entity's(each cabin, zone are called entity)*** from Server as entity id 1 located at `x, y coordinates (100, 150)`. Based on this i need to plot the entity on the screen. The sample floor looks like the below image.
[image]

can anyone suggest me the best way to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Canvas API to draw you views on any coordinate .

You can find an example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).

Comment: I tried with Canvas, It is okay if i use one single view. But in my case i am doing in a loop, every entity is co-related with other.

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.