# Create a floor plan in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I need to create a floor plan in Android, which is basically the same problem reported by [Create floor plan in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789865/create-floor-plan-in-android).

I'm currently using the Canvas component to draw it, but it's not scaling well when I got hundreds of rectangles.
This floor plan is also dynamic, and I need to change some styling as the server changes its representation.