# Is there a way to make a scrollable chart in JetPack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So, I have a very simple graph defined through Canvas. I want to make this graph scrollable (horizontally).

I know that I can make scrollable lists through LazyRow/LazyColumn. My current "thought" process looks like this: "I can create LazyRow and use my list of values to draw a line inside of each "item" of LazyRow."

In other words the algorithm would be something like that:

1. Pass list of values to items() inside of the LazyRow()
2. For each item, calculate the starting and ending points
3. Use Canvas inside of that "item" scope to draw a line from starting to ending point
4. Repeat from 2 until all lines are drawn

Even though I haven't coded it yet, I'm pretty sure this "approach" will work... However it looks a bit over-complicated...

I thought, maybe, it could be possible to just draw the whole chart and make it scrollable through modifier or something like that. I looked at API documentation for Compose Canvas, Modifier and etc. but I couldn't find something useful to me... probably I'm blind.

Comment: [example of scrollable and zoomable chart](https://github.com/ShirobokovNE/MarketChart)

Comment: @vitidev would you follow the same approach if you need to scroll on both axes?
I believe that'd also solve my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72565488/create-a-floor-plan-in-compose

Answer (score 0):

To make your `Canvas` horizontally scrollable you just need to set `width` and `horizontalScroll` modifier like below:

```
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .width(2000.dp)
        .height(300.dp)
) { 
   // ...
}
```